# Why does `export` fail on bad substitutions but not command failures?

Tags: bash, language-lawyer

It’s well known that [`export` masks the return value of command
substitutions in its variable assignments](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155). But, interestingly,
`export` does *not* mask the return value of failed substitutions:

```sh
$ (set -eu; export FOO="$(bad_command)"); echo $?
bash: bad_command: command not found
0
$ (set -eu; export FOO="${bad_variable}"); echo $?
bash: bad_variable: unbound variable
1
$ (set -eu; export FOO="${}"); echo $?  # bad substitution
bash: ${}: bad substitution
1
```

(Similar behavior in `dash`.)

What part of the specification indicates that failure of command
substitution does not propagate through `export`, but failure of
parameter expansion does?

Relevant sections from `man bash` (GNU Bash 4.4):

> ```sh
> set -u
> ```
>
> Treat unset variables and parameters other than the
>   special parameters "@" and "*" as an error when performing parameter
>   expansion. If expansion is attempted on an unset variable or
>   parameter, the shell prints an error message, and, if not interactive,
>   exits with a non-zero status.

and

> ```sh
> export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...
> export -p
> ```
>
> The supplied `names` are marked for automatic export to the
>   environment of subsequently executed commands. If the `-f` option is
>   given, the names refer to functions. If no names are given, or if the
>   `-p` option is supplied, a list of names of all exported variables is
>   printed. The `-n` option causes the export property to be removed from
>   each `name`. If a variable name is followed by `=word`, the value of
>   the variable is set to `word`. `export` returns an exit status of 0
>   unless an invalid option is encountered, one of the `names` is not a
>   valid shell variable name, or `-f` is supplied with a `name` that is
>   not a function.

—I don’t see anything here that would distinguish between the two cases.
In particular, `export` just says that the value of the variable “is set
to” `word`, which suggests that it goes through the normal expansion
process (which it does) without special treatment.

POSIX specification references:

- [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)
- [The `export` special builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/export.html)
- [The `set` special builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html)

Answer (score 2):

Neither case is really up to `export`

A command substitution just becomes text (empty or not) in a command's argument array. The Unix process model does not have any mechanism for relaying whether the text came from a program, or whether that program was successful.

This means that it's not possible to write an external command that behaves differently when you run `foo var="$(true)"` vs `foo var="$(false)"` vs `foo var=""` and shell builtins like `export` traditionally follow the same behavior for ease of implementation.

With `set -u` and unset variables, the command never runs at all. The shell simply skips execution if it encounters this condition while building the argument array, and reports failure instead. A command can't choose to ignore such a failure, since it's never consulted.

It would certainly be possible to implement a new shell mode that similarly skips execution and reports failure if command substitutions fail during the construction of the argument array, but this has not been a traditional feature so it's not in the POSIX spec.